# Minipar to stanford NLP dependencies

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to know what is the equivalent of minipar's "pnmod" in staford's dependencies.

As per this page : https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch18.html#sec:parsers:minipar:GR
pnmod stands for post nominal modifier.

Reading the stanford dependencies manual http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf
it seems to me that pnmod would match multiple of stanfords deps.

Which are they ?